# deleting occurances of a string of another string

Tags: c, string

I found this function that removes all occurances of a string of another string ,still i don't  understand how it works since it didn't modife the variable ch but it changed the variable p instead.
Here is the function:

```
void enlever1(char* ch,char* sch)
{
    char* p;
    do
    {
        p=strstr(ch,sch);
        if(p) strcpy(p,p+strlen(sch));
    }
    while(p);
}
```

Comment: strcpy shouldn't be used anyway, you should know your buffers size and use strncpy

Comment: This function actually works,the problem is: I don't know WHY it does, since ch wasn't changed in the function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, string is stored as array inside a memory, and mulitple pointers may point to a single string.

On success, `strstr` returns a pointer to the first occurrence of `sch` in the string pointed with `ch`. Now, the `p` pointer points to the part of the original string - when you change string with `p` pointer, you will change the original string.

Here's the simplified example: imagine you have a string which is stored in memory like this:

```
Hello World!\0 
^            ^
|            |
ch          end of string character
```

Now, let's say that you execute `p = strstr(ch, "Wo")`. The `p` pointer will point to the part of the original string:

```
Hello World!\0 
^     ^      ^
|     |      |
ch    p     end of string character
```

Now, if you change `p`, you will also change the `ch`:

```
p[0] = 'T'; /* change the first character to T */
```

This will result:

```
Hello Torld!\0 
^     ^      ^
|     |      |
ch    p     end of string character
```

And `printf(ch)` will print:

```
Hello Torld!
```

Comment: thank you alot 
If i understood well,any modification on the pointers that point to a single string will modifie that string

Answer (score 0):

`strstr` does not remove the occurrence but locates `sch` in `ch`.  Your variable `p` points to where the string contained in `sch` is found in `ch`.  If such a string is not found, it returns `NULL` that gets assigned to `p`.